# Calculate time differences in log file using Powershell based on linux code

Tags: powershell, datetime

EDITED:

```
Text1.txt:
123.456.789.189:12345
222.222.222.444:56789
451.200.111.321:55555
333.333.333.111:11223
```

I want to compare ID with IP that weren't registered.

ERROR:

```
Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: '123.456.789.189:12345'  Key being added: '123.456.789.189:12345'" +     $nameHash.Add( $data3[4], $data3[3] )
```

I think this error is due to the existence of duplicates.

How do I solve an issue with duplicates in Hash Table?

My function to calculate time takes in a startdate and an end date.

```
Function calTimeDiff( $StartDate, $EndDate ) 
{
    "which is = " + (NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $StartDate –End $EndDate).Hours + " hours, " + 
    (NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $StartDate –End $EndDate).Minutes + " minutes, " + 
    (NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $StartDate –End $EndDate).Seconds + " seconds, " + 
    "diff = " + (NEW-TIMESPAN –Start $StartDate –End $EndDate).TotalSeconds + " sec"
}

$lines1 = Get-Content "C:\Temp\Text1.txt" | Select-Object -Unique
$lines2 = Get-Content "C:\Temp\Text2.txt" | Select-Object -Unique

ForEach( $line2 in $lines2 )
{    
    $list = ( $date, $time, $client, $clientIP )
    $list = $line2.Split( "" )
    ForEach( $line1 in $lines1 )
    {
        $disconnectIP = $line1

        If( $disconnectIP -match $list[3] )
        {  
           $date = $list[0]
           $time = $list[1]
           $client = $list[2]
           $clientIP = $list[3] 

           If( $client -eq "serviceClient" )
           {
                $start = $date + " " + $time
           }

           If( $client -eq "Unregistered" )
           {
                $end = $date + " " + $time
           }

           calTimeDiff $start $end 
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean two clients with the same ip? it depends on your needs (you could determine both differences, only the first or only the last one)... Also - did you tried anything yet?

Comment: Could you be more clear about what is in the file and what is not? And what exactly is your problem? Maybe add some sample code..

Comment: Calculating time differences in Powershell is much simpler if you operate on objects rather than convert everything to text and then operate on text.  You haven't described what your inputs look like.  Are they objects or are they text?

Answer (score 2):

How about something along these lines?  I think it's basically behaving the way you were asking for (although you might want to tweak the display-span function a bit...)

```
#requires -Version 3
function parse-log 
{
    param(
        [string]$line
    )

    $data = $line.split(' ')
    $dateString = '{0} {1}' -f $data[0], $data[1]
    $timeStamp = Get-Date -Date $dateString
    [pscustomobject]@{
        TimeStamp = $timeStamp
        Client    = $data[2]
        IPAddress = $data[3]
    }
}

function display-span
{
    param(
        $logSpan
    )

    '{0} ({1}) ==> {2}' -f $logSpan.IPAddress, $nameHash.Get_Item( $logSpan.IPAddress), $logSpan.Start
    '{0} ({1}) ==> {2}' -f $logSpan.IPAddress, $nameHash.Get_Item( $logSpan.IPAddress), $logSpan.End
    'Start = {0}, End = {1}, diff = {2}' -f $logSpan.Start, $logSpan.End, $logSpan.TimeSpan
    ''
}

$ipStateHash = @{}
$nameHash = @{}
$logArray = @()

$lines1 = Get-Content -Path '.\Text1.txt'
$lines2 = Get-Content -Path '.\Text2.txt'
$lines3 = Get-Content -Path '.\Text3.txt'

# Build Name Hash
foreach( $line3 in $lines3 )
{
    $data3 = $line3.Split( ' ' )
    $nameHash.Add( $data3[4], $data3[3] )
}

foreach( $line2 in $lines2 ) 
{
    $entry = parse-log -line $line2
    switch( $entry.Client ) {
        'serviceClient' 
        {
            if( $lines1 -contains $entry.IPAddress ) 
            { 
                if( $ipStateHash.ContainsKey( $entry.IPAddress ) -eq $false ) 
                {
                    $ipStateHash.Add( $entry.IPAddress, $entry.TimeStamp )
                }
            }
        }
        'Unregistered' 
        {
            if( $ipStateHash.ContainsKey( $entry.IPAddress ) -eq $true ) 
            {
                $start = $ipStateHash.Get_Item( $entry.IPAddress )
                $ipStateHash.Remove( $entry.IPAddress )
                $timespan = $entry.TimeStamp - $start

                $logArray += [pscustomobject]@{
                    IPAddress = $entry.IPAddress
                    Start     = $start
                    End       = $entry.TimeStamp
                    TimeSpan  = $timespan
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$logArray | ForEach-Object -Process {
    display-span -logSpan $_ 
}

"IPs that weren't Unregistered:"
$ipStateHash.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -Property TimeStamp | ForEach-Object -Process {
    '{0} ==> {1}' -f $nameHash.Get_Item( $_.Key ), $_.Value 
}
```

Using your updated data files from above, the script outputs:

```
123.456.789.189:12345 (BOB) ==> 7/29/2015 6:00:13 AM
123.456.789.189:12345 (BOB) ==> 7/29/2015 6:00:19 AM
Start = 7/29/2015 6:00:13 AM, End = 7/29/2015 6:00:19 AM, diff = 00:00:06

222.222.222.444:56789 (ALICE) ==> 7/29/2015 6:00:18 AM
222.222.222.444:56789 (ALICE) ==> 7/29/2015 6:00:22 AM
Start = 7/29/2015 6:00:18 AM, End = 7/29/2015 6:00:22 AM, diff = 00:00:04

451.200.111.321:55555 (TOM) ==> 7/29/2015 6:20:03 AM
451.200.111.321:55555 (TOM) ==> 7/29/2015 6:21:19 AM
Start = 7/29/2015 6:20:03 AM, End = 7/29/2015 6:21:19 AM, diff = 00:01:16

IPs that weren't Unregistered:
BOB ==> 7/29/2015 6:01:00 AM
```

Comment: What if I have more IP in Text1.txt? Does it loop through all of them?

Comment: It's built an array of IPs from Text1.txt.  The `-contains` checks to see if the IP we pull from Text2.txt is a member of that array, so there's no reason to loop through Text1.txt...  I didn't bother checking with the "Unregistered" clause, since if it's not in the file, it couldn't have made it in the hash table from the "serviceClient" clause.

Comment: I just copied/pasted your text1/text2 files that you have up there and it still works for me.  I'll update my answer with the new output.

Comment: Added some code to dump out the `$ipStateHash` hash, which contains all of the serviceClients that weren't Unregistered.

Comment: So I have another Text3.txt that I want to compare with the $ipStateHash. Instead of displaying the IP, it will display the name. How can I replace the IP with the name? Please see EDITED code.

Comment: It's actually a fairly trivial change to make keeping with what I've got above.  Read the 3rd file into another array using `get-content`.  Build another hash, let's call it `$nameHash` using the IP address as the key, and the name as the value.  Then just get the value from the hash in the last line.  I'll update the code one last time...

Comment: A spin off question. Can I use the same name hash to replace the IP in function display-span, or add the name next to it? I'm thinking of writing the display-span to file. Then parse it and compare with the name from text3.txt

Comment: That means that a second serviceClient line for an ip/port combo is being seen before an Unregister line is being seen.   How you handle this is going to depend on what this means... Is this an error and the first serviceClient should be dropped? Is this to be expected and you need to somehow pair them ip (first service w/ first Unregister, or most recent service matched with most recent unregister)?  The first one is an easy fix, the second one is going to require a bit more coding...

Comment: Maybe I should remove the date/time in Text3.txt and only get the unique name/IP to fix the duplicates. Please see EDITED text.

Comment: Sorry, I apparently completely mis-read your last comment... I was thinking it was throwing the error on Text1, not Text3... :)  You can check for the existence of a key before the add (something like `if( -not $nameHash.ContainsKey( $data[4] ) { do the $nameHash.Add() here }`

Comment: How do you determine if Tom or Tom2 should be associated with a record if they are the same?